# Can social-auth Android add friends?

Tags: android, socialauth

I've been messing around with [social-auth Android](https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android) have been referring to the readme and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=457153) website. I haven't found a way to request a friend or follow someone via twitter. does social-auth have this functionality?